# How do I install UBUNTU TOUCH in Nokia XL?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nokia

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch in Nokia XL (Software Version 1.2.3.2) ? My phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

There is neither active, nor discontinued ports for the phone. So, you would need to do this all for yourself. I would not recommend it, because it would a tremendous work, and the phone is too low-end anyway.